# How to call a server side function on Leave event of a ASP.Net TextBox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, textbox

I am building a user registration form in asp.net. I want to check if the username is available or not on the leave event of the TextBox. I am not able to get the Leave Event of the TextBox.

Should I use OnBlur event of the Html TextBox.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `TextChanged` server-side event and wrapping the whole thing in an `UpdatePanel` for very quick ajax functionality.
If you use this method make sure the `AutoPostBack` property is set to `true` for the `TextBox` control.

Comment: But that will fire a query on every text changed. I think this will create more load on server

Comment: TextChanged is only fired when the user leaves the textbox - it's not fired every time a character is entered

Comment: oh, if thats the case, I am good to go with TextChanged. Thanks.